# Multiple SELECT statements in JPA Repository with @Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I was trying to execute select statement with subnets, with **@Query** annotation with '**nativeQuery = true**' in repository.
But it gives me the following error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"

The following is the query that gives me error

```
@Query(value="SELECT COUNT(cc.customer) AS tot FROM SELECT DISTINCT new RatingsAndReviews(c.customer,c.customerRating) FROM RatingsAndReviews AS c WHERE c.vehicle=?1 AS cc WHERE cc.customerRating=?2",nativeQuery = true)
    Integer getNoOfRatingsForStars(Vehicle vehicle,double starNumber);
```

The query is basically to select the ratings count for a particular starNumber out of 5 stars for a particular vehicle by customers.

The sub SELECT query alone gives the expected results when executed as below

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT new RatingsAndReviews(c.customer,c.customerRating)  FROM RatingsAndReviews AS c WHERE c.vehicle=?1")
    List<RatingsAndReviews> getCustomersWhoRatedVehicle(Vehicle vehicle);
```

My result set for the above query is; An array of RatingsAndReviews objects

```
[
    {
        "customerRating": 2.0,
        "customer": {
            "customerId": 1,
            },
        },
    },
    {
        "customerRating": 3.0,
        "customer": {
            "customerId": 2,
            },
        },
    },
    {
        "customerRating": 2.0,
        "customer": {
            "customerId": 3,
            },
        },
    }
]
```

So what I want to get is the count of ratings from customers for particular no. of stars. For example,How many 3 stared ratings, 2 stared ratings... and so on.

Query without setting 'nativeQuery = true' will Be:

```
 @Query("SELECT COUNT(cc.customer) AS tot FROM (SELECT DISTINCT new RatingsAndReviews(c.customer,c.customerRating)  FROM RatingsAndReviews AS c WHERE c.vehicle=?1) AS cc WHERE cc.customerRating=?2")
    Integer getNoOfRatingsForStars(Vehicle vehicle,double star);
```

and this will give the following error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Integer

please correct me if what I've done with the query is wrong and any sort help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of the `Vehicle` type. That may not translate properly as a native query. Try making it a `String` type (if that makes sense) by calling `.toString()` (or `.name()` if it's an enum) before calling the JPA method.

Comment: @karmakaze, I didn't really follow or understand your suggestion above. however, the output for the working piece of query is edited above.

Comment: The query language (part of @Query in the quotes) is a different format when `nativeQuery = true` is used compared to when `nativeQuery = true` is not used. When you use `nativeQuery = true` the format should be the same syntax of SQL used when entering commands directly using a database client. The only special difference are the parameter placeholders `?1`, `?2` etc.

When `nativeQuery = true` is not used, the format is called JPQL which something between SQL and Java. So all the JPQL parts in the working second query has to be translated to SQL for use with `nativeQuery`.

Comment: @karmakaze, thank you very much for the tip. Can I know whether ```select statement with subnets ``` can be written without making ```nativeQuery = true```

Comment: @karmakaze, I was able to get the result with ```nativeQuery = true``` when I tested my query in the database and used the same in the program. But I would like to know how the same result can be generated without using ```nativeQuery = true```.

Comment: For the part of the error message saying `Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Integer`, perhaps the result type doesn't match what's expected. Try using `Long` or `BigInteger` instead of `Integer` and see if that gives any better results.

Answer (score 0):

First test the syntax of the query in your db query client manually: e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(cc.customer) AS tot
  FROM
    SELECT DISTINCT new RatingsAndReviews(c.customer,c.customerRating)
    FROM RatingsAndReviews AS c
    WHERE c.vehicle='some test value here' AS cc
  WHERE cc.customerRating=<some test value here>
```

There are numerous syntax issues with the above, for instance you can't use `new Type()` and should reference table names rather than class names.